# Crashing on this piece of code

Tags: c, crash, switch-statement

```
void grupo1(){
int x;
system("cls");
printf("*Alcalinos*\n");
printf("Introduzca el periodo: ");
scanf("%i\n",x);
system("cls");
switch(x){
    case 1:printf("(1)Hidrogeno");
    break;
    case 2:printf("(2)Litio");
    break;
    case 3:printf("(3)Sodio");
    break;
    case 4:printf("(4)Potasio");
    break;
    case 5:printf("(5)Rubido");
    break;
    case 6:printf("(6)Cesio");
    break;
    case 7:printf("(7)Francio");
    break;
    system("cls");
    default:printf("Error: Ese numero no corresponde a ningun periodo valido en ese grupo");    }}
```

When i press 1 to select the first case(Hydrogen) the program crashes,someone knows why?
Full code [Here](http://codepaste.net/riruno).
(it's a periodic table)
The code isn't finished,just the "lithium family" alkali metals (Alcalinos)

Comment: Check and find what's wrong with your `scanf("%i\n",x);`

Comment: `scanf("%i\n",x);` needs to be `scanf("%i\n", &x);`.

Comment: `scanf("%i\n",x);` --> `scanf("%i", &x);` : `scanf` requires the address.

Comment: Note that the third occurrence of `system("cls");` will not be executed, sitting between `break;` and `default:`

Comment: Note that the `"%i\n"` format is not a good choice.  The input won't terminate until you have typed a number and something which is neither white space nor part of the first number (so, for example, you might type ` 123\n\n\n\nWTF!` and the input doesn't stop until you type the `W`).  This is normally considered unfriendly behaviour; don't end an interactive `scanf()` format string with a white space character.  In this case, use just `"%i"`.  If you 're reading a single character, it's often (normally?) correct to use `" %c"` (note the space before the `%c` and no white space after it).

Comment: When you say "program crashes", what does that mean?  It sits there doing nothing?  Or it generates an error message?  If it just sits there, then the trailing white space is the problem.  If it crashes and generates an error message, part of the trouble may be that you're not checking whether the input succeeded or not.  You should be doing that, too.

Answer (score 1):

from your [code](http://codepaste.net/riruno), group1-18 use

`int x;
...
scanf("%i\n",x);`// bug here,

x is still unknow, try

```
scanf("%i\n",&x);,
```

Comment: Yes,i forgot **&x**     _scanf("%i",&x);_

Answer (score 0):

There was a \n after receiving the desired input, that is why it was waiting for the enter key to be pressed. If you take it out and do:

```
void grupo1(){
    int x;
    system("cls");
    printf("*Alcalinos*\n");
    printf("Introduzca el periodo: ");
    scanf("%i",&x);

    switch(x){
        case 1:printf("(1)Hidrogeno\n");
        break;
        case 2:printf("(2)Litio\n");
        break;
        case 3:printf("(3)Sodio\n");
        break;
        case 4:printf("(4)Potasio\n");
        break;
        case 5:printf("(5)Rubido\n");
        break;
        case 6:printf("(6)Cesio\n");
        break;
        case 7:printf("(7)Francio\n");
        break;
        system("cls");
        default:printf("Error: Ese numero no corresponde a ningun periodo valido en ese grupo");
    }
}
```